# Uncompress a gzip file from CURL, on php

Tags: php, curl, gzip, gunzip

Does anyone know how to uncompress the contents of a gzip file that i got with curl?

for example: http://torcache.com/torrent/63ABC1435AA5CD48DCD866C6F7D5E80766034391.torrent

responded

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 01:11:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent
Content-Length: 52712
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 Jun 2010 15:09:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Fri, 09 Jul 2010 01:11:26 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

then the compressed gzip,

i tried gzdecode but doesn't work , gzeflate as well doesn't they simply don't get any response, and the contents of the files are no more than 2k

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`gzdecode`](http://php.net/gzdecode):

```
<?php
    $c = file_get_contents("http://torcache.com/" .
        "torrent/63ABC1435AA5CD48DCD866C6F7D5E80766034391.torrent");
    echo gzdecode($c);
```

gives

```
d8:announce42:http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/announce13:announce-listll42
...
```

Comment: yes true, but I have php 5.2, and they say that gzdecode is available since 6.0 only

I have a gentoo with php and zlib configured , and i can't seem to have available those gz functions. Any ideeas? :)

Comment: Ok, i have a solution , no pretty because i had to write to a file the contents, and not only use a string :

function gzdecode($data){
  $g=tempnam('/tmp','ff');
  @file_put_contents($g,$data);
  ob_start();
  readgzfile($g);
  $d=ob_get_clean();
  unlink($g);
  return $d;
}

and it works :)

Comment: @PartySoft That function is great!

Comment: @PartySoft Thanks for that! Worked like a charm. Running 5.3.X and had no luck with [gzuncompress()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php).

Comment: I suggest to use the $length parameter as it guards your script of insufficient memory errors. For example `$contents = gzdecode($contents, 10485760);` will stop decompression if the result will be more than 10 MB. I had several websites that were < 1 MB in gzipped size and after `gzdecode()` they raised to 30 MB! If you prefer CURLOPT_ENCODING you should try CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION if you are able stop the decompression result by that as well. I did not test it.

Comment: what the heck, no, just set CURLOPT_ENCODING to "gzip" and curl will automatically decompress gzip-encoded responses

Answer (score 88):

Just tell cURL to decode the response automatically whenever it's gzipped

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Comment: Value should be empty string or encoding type. not int

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this be a sensible default CURL setting?

Comment: @redben [My proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/340974) was declined in 2011 and now AlixAxel's was approved. :(

Comment: use 'curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');' if you want to avoid encoding, per [link](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html)

Answer (score 13):

libcurl offers a feature that makes it decompress the contents automatically (if built with zlib).

See the CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING option: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the header stating that you accept gzip encoding as follows?:

```
curl_setopt($rCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'));
```

Comment: he's already receiving it encoded, so I don't think declaring that he accepts it encoded would do any difference. I tried sending the server Accept-encoding: none and the server did not comply.

Answer (score 1):

With a [zlib Stream Wrapper:](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php)

```
file_get_contents("compress.zlib://http://torcache.com/" .
    "torrent/63ABC1435AA5CD48DCD866C6F7D5E80766034391.torrent");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`gzuncompress`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) or [`gzinflate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php)?

`gzdeflate` **compresses**, the opposite of what you want. To be honest, I can't figure out how `gzdecode` differs from normal uncompressing.

There's also the cURL option [`CURLOPT_ENCODING`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. **This enables decoding of the response.** Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.

It seems to mean it'll automatically decompress the response, but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with gzinflate (pretending that $headers contains all your HTTP headers, and $buffer contains your data):

```
if (isset($headers['Content-Encoding']) && ($headers['Content-Encoding'] === 'gzip' || $headers['Content-Encoding'] === 'deflate'))
    {
        if ($headers['Content-Encoding'] === 'gzip')
        {
            $buffer = substr($buffer, 10);
        }
        $contents = @gzinflate($buffer);
        if ($contents === false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```