# php - download zip file with curl and unzip it?

Tags: php, unzip

Hi is there any possibility to download a zip file with curl and unzip it on the fly without to save the file ot the disc?

For example:

```
.
.
.

$resultZip = curl_exec($curl);

$result = some_unzip_way($resultZip);
```

Thanks!
Nik

Answer (score 0):

php curl has a flag to unzip content if needed

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '')`

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277224/1660762)

Answer (score -3):

Its not super easy, php has zip functions, but require a file to exist.  Look at the first comment on this page, the guy describes your exact scenario and gives some code:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php

Comment: You could also probably use exec and pipe the data to the command line zip functions.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps Perl is a better choice for that kind of operation.